# PHP Insert to MYSql after checking existed value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to register users in my app and i tried to check if the age is existed then stop the registration process, I wrote my code to register users and worked very well but when I tried to validate the registration using check_age function it doesn't work well and still allow registration even if the age is existed can anyone tell me what is missed with my code :
here is my code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
       require "init.php";

       creat_Student();
}
function creat_Student()
{
    global $con;
    $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $age=$_POST["age"];

    if(strcmp(check_age(), '0') == 0)
    {
    $query="Insert Into student(firstname,lastname,age) values ('$firstname','$lastname','$age');";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else 
    echo "not true";

}
function check_age()
{
    global $con;
    $age=$_POST["age"];
    echo " $age";
    $temp_arr=array();

    $query="SELECT * FROM  student where age ='{$age}'; ";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $num_of_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($num_of_rows==0)
    return '0';
    else 
    return '1';

}
```

Comment: There are a few thing that are a little off place. Why wold a user registration will depend by the age that way? What is the application of this? You also need some sanitizing or use prepared statements.

Comment: Safe advice (may not resolve your issue), initialize your variables first, before trying to perform some tasks on those (for example : you check if `$num_of_rows` is greater than 0, but where did you initialized this variable ?).

Comment: Oh, and strcmp() ??? why??? return false/true or 0 and 1, if is that smart to evaluate an integer to true and false.

Comment: I am developing android app and my app depends on age , I am new to php so i saw that they use strcmp to compare values, correct me if this is wrong

Comment: Another advice: Only omit curly braces for `if` statements when you know what you're doing. In this case, it doesn't behave as you might think.

Comment: Surely if you are registering student, Almost EVERYBODY in one years intake will have the same AGE

Comment: is choosing Age as parameter to compare with, the reason for not working properly?? . I may change it to check the username or anything else but i will face the same problem

Comment: is not the reason, but is not correct as thinking mode, i suggest you to try a more OOP solution for this.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as mention is comments above, there are some sanitizing needed.

But here is what i suggest..

1. Change `check_age()` function and pass parameter of age in it as below and return `$num_of_rows`.

   ```
   function check_age($age)
   {
      global $con;

      $query="SELECT * FROM  student where age =".$age;
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
      return mysqli_num_rows($result);
   }
   ```
2. Then in `creat_Student()` function `if` condition will change like...

   ```
   function creat_Student()
   {
     global $con;
     $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
     $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
     $age=$_POST["age"];

     if(!check_age($age))
     {
       $query="Insert Into student(firstname,lastname,age) values ('$firstname','$lastname','$age');";
       mysqli_query($con,$query);
       mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else
       echo "not true";
   }
   ```

Thanks, Jay.

Answer (score 0):

I added another field, you should add it to the database and form "userName" that should be unique VAR_CHAR in database.
 But you should really go for more OOP version if you ever want to learn real PHP.
 Make an abstract Entity class for DB, then the database tables can extend it like class Stundent extends Entity and have methods like get, insert, delete, update.(You should take a look at some PHP Frameworks). 
 Here i tried to make a fast and easy correction for your code:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    require "init.php";

    addStudent();
}

function addStudent()
{
    /**
     * @var mysqli $conn
     */
    global $conn;
    $userName  = $_POST['userName'];
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  student WHERE username ='$userName'; ";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows == 0) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO student(`firstname`, `lastname`, `age`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstName, $lastName, $age);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Student already registered in the database!";
    }
}
```